# requirement for my project

Tags: android, web-services, joomla, project, webservice-client

*(before starting sorry for my wrong vocabs or grammer in english , since my native language is not english, but if any one could understand plz help me out)*

hi, i need help regarding my one university project, i m going to make an android based application,

the basic idea of the project is that the user of the application will retrieve/update any data from/to database on remote computer(suppose i have database on my computer of personal contact information and want to view/edit that information, remotely from any where) via GPRS and WIFI.

**what comes in my mind is this;**

i have to create a webserver with a web application, through which the mobile application send/retrieve information by sending some queries+data on the webserver, from there webserver runs/executes the queries on DATABASE and after executing it, the result will send back to the mobile application(android).

**(Q1)** is the above thinking is right?? or is there any other way easier than that?

**(HELP)** also the problem i am facing is that i dont know the implementation of how my mobile application will connect with webserver and access to database!! if any one could provide me the basic ***code/tutorials/links*** etc for that i really thankful!! and i have not much time left for completing my project.

i have idea in my mind, but dont know my direction of thinking is right or not and how i am going to implement it, for that i want to give example what exactly i want to do;

for example i want to view list of contacts(or any information), for that 'show' command will send to the webserver (on clicking the button in the mobile application), the webserver execute the query for example 'select * from dbcontacts' and then webserver send that list to the mobile application.

**NOTE:**
for webserserver; i will use XAMPP
for webapplication; i will use JOOMLA, etc
for databse; ORACLE
my project is basically to make such application for android mobile phones, so for mobile application i will work on ANDROID

Comment: The android developer sight has a lot of examples for different types of applications.  I imagine if you look there will be some that are applicable to your problem.  Does your application *have* to be both sides?  Or could you develop the android app for you project and use something like a google account to manage your online contacts etc?

Answer (score 0):

You can use XML-RPC to communicate between the Android app and the Joomla web app, which Joomla has support for. To use XML-RPC from Android you can use e.g. http://code.google.com/p/android-xmlrpc/

**However**, since Android apps are written in Java, why not use a Java-based app server and write *all* your code in Java? That might make things easier, since you say you don't have much time. I don't know much about Joomla but I know that with Java there are several options for how to do network communication between apps.